# How do you make this graph with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this graph, how do you graph with `tikz` code?

**Translation**: In the graphic shown we have AQ=5cm, QP=4cm and BC=3cm (D, C and T are points for the tangents). Calculate the area of the shaded region (AOP).

*Probably* A) to E) are multiple choice answers.

[image]

---

For the graph to make sense: AP must be 7.6088 and AQ must be 2.8875.[image]

Comment: It is not very difficult to produce this if *all* the relevant input is specified in English.

Comment: The measurements do not go well. Try to graph it.

Comment: What is given, initially? The triangle AOP? Is it supposed to be isosceles (not very clear from the figur?

Answer (score 10):

You can draw it using geogebra and export to tikz

[image]

Comment: Good to know! Could you link the way to export from geogebra yo tikz, please?

Comment: Go to File/Export/PGF TikZ.

Comment: I know, but I don't get a teh graph real.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest an elementary solution below for the drawing but not for the configuration your problem is talking about.  That configuration does not exist.  The solution uses one parameter.  In the usual Cartesian coordinate system centered at *O*, the parameter is *b*, the *x* coordinate of *B* and so, the radius of the big circle.  Since *BC=3*, the measure of the angle *TOC* is determined by *b*; so the tangent line of the big circle at *T* is known as well.  Moreover, since *AQ=5*, the line *(AQ)* is also known.  It follows that there is a single value for *b* such that the line *(OP)* is tangent to the small circle at *D*.  But for this value of *b*, *PQ* does not equal *4* as stated.

The commented code allows you to verify the tangency condition at *D*.  Just change *b* value and see what happens.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm, 11pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, matrix, intersections, math, calc}

\begin{document}

\tikzmath{%
  real \b, \ang, \r;
  \b = 4.9107;
  \ang = 2*atan((3/(2*\b-3)));
  \r = (\b-3)/cos(\ang);
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[clip] (-\b-1, -1) rectangle (\b+1, 2*\b);
  \path 
  (0, 0) coordinate (O)
  (\b, 0) coordinate (B)
  (-\b, 0) coordinate (A)
  (\b-3, 0) coordinate (C)
  (\ang: \b) coordinate (T);
  
  \draw[name path=circle] (O) circle (\b);
  \draw ($(A)!-.1!(B)$) -- ($(A)!1.1!(B)$);
  
  \path[name path=circle_A] (A) circle (5);
  \path[name intersections={of=circle and circle_A, by={Q}}];
  \draw[name path=AQ] (A) -- ($(A)!2!(Q)$);
  
  \path[name path=OT] (O) -- (T);
  \path[name path=CO'] (C) -- +(0, \b);
  \path[name intersections={of=OT and CO', by={O'}}];
  \draw[name path=small circle] (O')
    let \p1 = ($(O')-(C)$) in circle ({veclen(\x1,\y1)});
  
  \draw[name path=tangent_T] ($(T)!1!90:(O')$) -- ($(T)!1.7!-90:(O)$);
  \path[name intersections={of=AQ and tangent_T, by={P}}];
  \draw[name path=OP] (P) -- (O);
  \path[name intersections={of=small circle and OP, by={D}}];
  
  \fill[gray, fill opacity=.2] (A) -- (P) -- (O) -- cycle;
  
  % %%% verifying the tangency condition at D
  % \draw[red, thin,
  % name intersections={of=small circle and OP, name=I, total=\t}]
  % \foreach \i in {1,...,\t}{(I-\i) circle (\i)};
  % \fill[red] (I-1) circle (1.7pt) node[right] {$D$};
  % \draw[red, thin] (Q) circle (4);
  
  \foreach \P/\pos in {%
    O/below left, A/below left, B/below right, C/below,
    T/above right, O'/above left, Q/above left, P/right, D/right%
  }{%
    \draw[fill=white] (\P) circle (1.5pt) node[\pos] {$\P$};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As you mentioned, it seems that with the values given in the example the graph does not exist.